# How to query a text column contains an array ["val1", "val2"] and retrieves all of the table that contains a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a problem with SQL logic, I have to check if the value of the category which is an array and which is in the database matches the numeric value to retrieve all the elements that match, need to help please

in my table product i have save category column like  varchar this:

[image: This is my category column from database]

and this is my request function:

```
function getCategoryTrendingProduct($categoryId, $skip, $limit)
{

    $sql    = "SELECT id as product_id, name as product_name, price as product_price, image as product_image, rating as product_rating, review as product_review FROM products WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(category, '$.?') = ?  ORDER BY product_sale DESC LIMIT ?, ?";

    $query  = $this->db->query($sql, array($categoryId, $skip, $limit));
    $rs     = $query->result_array();
    
    return $rs;
}
```

I want to extract the category column and verify that it contains categoryId..
help!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data *in a table format* would be helpful.

Comment: You will want the 4th row returned if `categoryId` is 11, 1st row if 6, and all rows except first if `$categoryId` is 1 right?

Comment: no because I have a product table and I would like to retrieve all the products that have the category specified, sorry if I did not explain well at first

Comment: SQL Server sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can split each value by comma then use it for category verify.
Example to splitting;

```
SELECT TRIM(TMP.value) AS SplittedDate
FROM (
    SELECT '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' AS col
    ) a
CROSS APPLY string_split(col, ',') AS TMP
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found an unorthodox but functional alternative with a simple LIKE but which searches for the element with the double quotes WHERE category LIKE '%"1"%, since the value is unique in each row. but I do not know if this affects the performance